# Image flipped in preview after taking photo from IPhone camera, how do I reverse this?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

When I take a photo within my app after hitting the shutter button the image preview is mirrored horizontally. I know it does this to mimic a mirror but I don't want this behaviour on my app. I want it to take front facing camera photos the way instagram does with no flip. I know how to flip the photo AFTER i.e.:

```
UIImage * flippedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:picture.CGImage scale:picture.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored];
```

but it's the preview image I want to flip (the image shown with the "Retake" and "Use Photo"). Any ideas how to go about this? I think I need to override something in the UIImagePicker class.

Thanks

Comment: Any code if you have tried so far?

Comment: I think I need to override something in the UIImagePickerController class, maybe I can copy the .m and .h files and make a custom class from it and use that instead. I'm not sure how to view Apple class files though

Comment: Does the phone orientation alter this? E.g. if you hold your phone upside down?

Comment: If you are open for custom cam use this  https://github.com/Aevit/SCCaptureCamera and change flip image in preview

Comment: ask question if you get any problem during editing code

Answer (score 2):

I tried a lot of answers described on stackoverlfow, but none of them offered the result I was looking for. Eiter the whole `UIImagePickerViewController` was transformed, so the camera was unintuitive, not like looking into a mirror, or only the image was transformed afterwards as you describe, what was working fine but you have a wrong preview of the image in-between. So I ended up with this hack, it's definitely not best-practice but works on iOS8 and 9 and gives me the result I need.

Make sure you add a observer to get notified when the capture image button was pressed:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "photoTaken", name: "_UIImagePickerControllerUserDidCaptureItem", object: nil)
```

In the `potoTaken` method you can do something like this to find the preview image and transform it to look like you expect it:

```
func photoTaken() {
        for subview in self.imagePicker.view.subviews {
            for subsubview in subview.subviews {
                for subsubsubview in subsubview.subviews {
                    for subsubsubsubview in subsubsubview.subviews {
                        for subsubsubsubsubview in subsubsubsubview.subviews {
                            for subsubsubsubsubsubview in subsubsubsubsubview.subviews {
                                for subsubsubsubsubsubsubview in subsubsubsubsubsubview.subviews {
                                    if subsubsubsubsubsubsubview.isKindOfClass(UIImageView) {
                                        subsubsubsubsubsubsubview.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.imagePicker.cameraViewTransform, -1, 1)
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And in your `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` delegate flip the image again before saving or displaying it.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {

            let flippedImage = UIImage(CGImage: pickedImage.CGImage!, scale: pickedImage.scale, orientation: .LeftMirrored)

            myCustomPhotoAlbum.sharedInstance.saveImage(flippedImage)
            self.imageView.image = flippedImage
        }

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: come on, you can replace it with one `while`

Comment: This doesn't work. You're missing subsubsubsubsubsubsubsubview

Answer (score 2):

You can refine code replace nest structure:

```
var subviews: [UIView] = [self.imagePicker.view]
while (!subviews.isEmpty) {
    let subview = subviews.removeFirst()
    subviews += subview.subviews
    if (subview.isKind(of: UIImageView.self)) {
        subview.transform = self.imagePicker.cameraViewTransform.scaledBy(x: -1, y: 1)
    }
}
```